# How to prevent microsoft windows from running on a pc

Tags: windows, linux, boot, bios, uefi

Suggest I have a PC with either a BIOS with the commonly available options or a UEFI. Is there any way to change the settings so NO Windows NT based System will boot anymore (not even Windows PE including the windows install DVDs). This should be achieved without affecting GNU/Linux live cds or installed GNU/Linux systems.

Thanks for your answers.

PS: This is kind of an idealist question and I hope this is not off topic.

PPS: I don't want to do this, it is just a proof of concept question.

Comment: No, this is a very bad idea.

Comment: @FrankThomas Suggest I want to give someone a computer and want him to be able to do anything he likes to but not to install windows (achieving this by a BIOS password).

Comment: Just as I think it's bad MS trying to make it difficult for Linux to run I think this is a bad idea. Users should be allowed to install whatever software they want on their PC!

Comment: @BradPatton You are right in terms of freedom but I wonder if it is technically possible.

Comment: you can password protect the bios, disable boot from external media and put a padlock on the case, but in the end, remember, "Physical access is root access. period."

Comment: @FrankThomas But then you can't boot GNU/Linux live cds anymore.

Comment: yeah, you are correct, there is no way to enforce what you want to do. even using advanced UEFI boot signing, it still is meaningless to any OS that doesn't use UEFI features (most linux, and all windows prior to win8), so you need to disable that requirement to install linux anyway.

Comment: @FrankThomas So the only way would be to remove the Microsoft Secure Boot key and add the keys of all available signed GNU/Linux bootloaders?

Comment: yes, if your OEM or Mobo-Vendor has provided that functionality, and the linux distro in question uses an UEFI secureboot bootloader. if your friend is any good though, they'll just swap them back.

Comment: Anything *you* can do to the computer, anyone else can undo. This certainly would be possible, for the hardware manufacturer, but obviously none of them would ever dream of doing this. Voting to close since [*You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face*.](http://superuser.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: @Dennis Never mind. I knew this question would probably be closed but I don't know any community where asking that kind of question is as much fun as on superuser.

Comment: Sorry, but we don't really do Community Wiki anymore. See: [The Future of Community Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)

Comment: IMHO, this should not have been closed; it *is* a practical, answerable question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on option #1 by FSMaxB, I've written a page with (mostly) step-by-step instructions for replacing your Secure Boot keys [here.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#add_keys) Note, however, that some of the details of what to select in the firmware's own user interface will be system-specific. There are also other ways to accomplish this goal. Adding new keys (as described shortly) will require steps not documented on that page.

This approach works to limit what the computer can boot, but it goes a little too far, in terms of FSMaxB's requirements. Specifically, it not only prevents Windows from booting, but it also prevents most Linux live CDs from booting. I can think of a number of ways to minimize this problem, but some of them are awkward and most of them work only on distributions that are Secure Boot-enabled:

- Add distributions' public keys to the Secure Boot keys in the computer and adjust their boot processes to bypass shim and to boot GRUB or some other boot loader directly. This requires altering files on the live CDs, though, which is a tedious task for technically unsavvy end users.
- Place a copy of [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) on the hard disk. This should enable redirecting the boot process to GRUB on a live CD, bypassing its copy of shim. In theory this should work for anything that uses shim, provided that the distribution's key is in the Secure Boot key list you've created.
- Place a copy of rEFInd on the hard disk, launched via the Linux Foundation's [PreBootloader.](http://blog.hansenpartnership.com/linux-foundation-secure-boot-system-released/) This will enable users to add hashes for any boot loader to the firmware, enabling them to launch any version of Linux, even if its boot loader and kernels are unsigned. This would probably also enable them to boot Windows, too, but at least they'd have to explicitly approve of this action.
- Place a copy of rEFInd on the hard disk, launched via shim. This has no advantage over the basic setup except that it makes it easier for users to add keys (via shim's MOK list). It's conceivable that the presence of shim would help with some boot loaders, though.
- Include in the set of keys you add to the Secure Boot list the public key that's paired with the one that Microsoft uses to sign third-party binaries. Since Microsoft signs its own products with a different key, this will enable the firmware to launch third-party tools, such as Ubuntu 12.10 or Fedora 18, but not to launch Microsoft's own version of Windows. Third-party Windows-based products, though, might be signed with the Microsoft third-party key and so would launch. Note that some plug-in cards have firmware that's signed with this key, too, so this action might be necessary to use such cards' firmware.

As to the suggestion that this is a bad idea, I disagree, provided it's what the machine's owner actually wants. In the days of DOS, it was common for computers to become infected by accidentally booting a floppy disk that contained a boot-sector virus. In principle, the same thing could happen today via a USB flash drive or CD-R. Shutting off that avenue of attack, even if it's not a common one today, is worthwhile. That said, I wouldn't recommend gifting or selling such a computer without making it clear to the recipient what's been done to it and providing instructions on how to undo the changes, if desired.

Answer (score 6):

I have asked this question so that people can have fun with the discussion that follows.

As I post this text as an answer, here are three possible ways to achieve this:

1. Having UEFI Secure Boot deleting the Microsoft key and adding keys used by GNU/Linux bootloaders (As of Frank Thomas' comment)
2. Using another processor architecture than x86 or windows 8 compatible ARM that is supported by the linux kernel (As of winfreak's answer).
3. Using a custom coreboot (http://www.coreboot.org) that prevents Windows from booting.